# ifstream or ofstream types called by template function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, fstream

I posted complete source code, I apologize to not have did it before.

**myclass.h:**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class MyClass
{
    public:

        /*
         * @Brief Constructor
         */
        MyClass();

        /*
         * @Brief Constructor
         * @param orig
         */
        MyClass(const MyClass & orig);

        /*
         * @Brief Destructor
         */
        virtual ~MyClass();

        template<typename T> bool openFile(T &file);

    private:

};

template <typename T>
class streamType
{
public:
        static bool isInStream() { return false; }
};

//
// Specialized for the ifstream
//
template<>
class streamType<std::ifstream>
{
public:
        static bool isInStream() { return true; }
};


#endif
```

**myclass.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass & orig)
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

template<typename T> bool MyClass::openFile(T &file)  
{
    std::string path, filename;

    if(streamType<T>::isInStream())
    {
        file.open(path + filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    }
    else
    {
        file.open(path + filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    }
}
```

**main:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "myclass.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;
    MyClass foo;

    if(foo.openFile(in))  //reading
    {
        // do something
        in.close();
    }
    if(foo.openFile(out))  // writing
    {   
        // do something
        out.close();  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At moment I have two errors but before only one ....??? confused

**the compiler error:**
undefined reference to "bool MyClass::openFile > >(std::basic_ifstream >&)"
undefined reference to "bool myfile::openFile > >(std::basic_ofstream >&)"
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Intel-Linux-x86/test] Error 1

Gg

Comment: Errors were meant to be read

Comment: did you remember to put templates only in header files?

Comment: So it is a linker error. I suspect that you define the template function in a cpp.

Comment: yes, in the same .h header file are defined: "openFile(T &file)", template <typename T> class streamType" and "template<> class streamType<std::ifstream>"

Comment: I think that you are missing include directive with the header file with openFile function definition. is it the case?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can't implement a templatized method on a .cpp file. You must define it in the .h. After all, new code must be generated each time the method is called with a new type, the compiler can't create a generic code inside a .cpp file.

Comment: I'm compiling Myclass.cpp and MyClass.h as a library and I'm linking it from main.cpp file

Comment: The declarations *and* definition need to be in the *header* file. You should not be using a .cpp file for `MyClass`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 what about `streamType`?

Comment: @G.Samaras Same deal. But IIRC the explicit specialization can be in a source file as long as there's a declaration in the header.

Comment: @0x499602D2 my compiler can't find it. Is it a C++ feature? From the search I made it looks more like a C# one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The declarations and definition need to be in the header file. You should not be using a .cpp file for MyClass. WAS THE CORRECT ANSWER!! I FORGET THAT TO PUT A TEMPLATE IN THE .CPP FILE I NEED TO WRITE "#DEFINE CURRENT_TYPE TYPE", IT IS CORRECT?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the definition of your `openFile()` from `myclass.h`. Then in `myclass.cpp`, replace the declaration of the function with its definition, like this:

```
    template<typename T>
    bool openFile(T &file)
    {
        std::string path, filename;

        if(streamType<T>::isInStream())
        {
            file.open(path + filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        }
        else
        {
            file.open(path + filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        }
        // you should return something in a fuunction returning a bool
    }
```

As  0x499602D2 said, the declarations and definition need to be in the header file.

However, now this line

`if(streamType<T>::isInStream())`

will result in an error like this:

```
error: ‘streamType’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
error: ‘::isInStream’ has not been declared
```

I am not sure if `streamType` is C++, it looks like a C# feature, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

> **The declarations and definition need to be in the header file. You
>   should not be using a .cpp file for MyClass. –  0x499602D2 2 hours
>   ago**

Is the correct answer!!

```
                                    or
```

put in the header file the declaration and the definition of a template function leaving in the .cpp other class functions because as said

> **Piotr S. "template functions are only in header file".**

It is also correct!!
thank you all

I know that there is a trick to put a template in the .cpp file but by my point of view it is not more a template.

trick: use a #define currentType T in the .cpp file.